# Open and close links with intervals

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, window.open

I was trying to make a program that opens a link, closes it after 3 seconds and opens the next one. I'll add more links, but I'd like the program to ask every 10 links "Are you there?". I thought of doing maybe an if statement, but not sure.

```
<script>
var links = ['www.youtube.com', 'www.yahoo.com', 'www.google.bg', 'www.facebook']

function openLinks(){
    window.open(links[0]);
    links++
}

function withIntervals(){
    setInterval(openLinks(), 3000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you opening multiple questions asking the same question?

Comment: @Kritner: they aren't quite the same, and looking at the dates it does appear the OP might have been trying to make progress themselves.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, but I never actually got to even start because the last questions I posted didn't really help me and were put away. I still need help, sorry...

Comment: @WhiteG you can edit your existing questions rather than creating new questions that are asking practically the same thing, especially if those previous questions don't already have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var currIndex = 0;

function openLinks(){
    window.open(links[currIndex++]);
    if (currIndex % 10 == 0) {
        if (confirm("Are you there yet?")) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

When `currIndex` is divisible by 10, the remainder will be `0`, so your `if` condition will be true.

You'll probably also want to keep the value returned by `setInterval` so you can clear it later with `clearInterval`.

Comment: Thanks, that's great! Would you happen to know how I can open links with intervals? I know the code above seems legit, but for some reason doesn't work. Can you help?